# Кастомный аллокатор

Tags: c++

Есть такой аллокатор:

```
template<class T>
class Allocator
{   
public:
    using value_type = T;

    Allocator() noexcept {}

    template<class _Other>
    Allocator(const Allocator<_Other>&) noexcept
    {   
        //std::cout << typeid(_Other).name() << std::endl;
    }

    void deallocate(T* const ptr, const size_t count)
    {   
        std::cout << "Allocator::deallocate " << ptr << std::endl;
        std::free(ptr);
    }

    T* allocate(const size_t count)
    {   
       if(count > std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / sizeof(T) )
            throw std::bad_alloc();

        void* ptr = std::malloc(count);
        std::cout << "Allocator::allocate " << ptr << std::endl;
        return static_cast<T*>(ptr);
    }
};

class A
{
public:

    A()
    {
        std::cout << "A() " << this << std::endl;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A() " << this  << std::endl;
    }
};
```

И так я его использую:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<A, Allocator<A>> vec;
    vec.push_back(A());
    return 0;
}
```

Вот что выводит программа:

```
Allocator::allocate 00ED7A48
A() 00DCFA33
Allocator::allocate 00ED7DA0
~A() 00DCFA33
~A() 00ED7DA0
Allocator::deallocate 00ED7DA0
Allocator::deallocate 00ED7A48
```

Почему вызывается конструктор `A()`?  Судя по [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) `std::malloc` не вызывает конструктор.

Не совсем понимаю почему программа падает с сообщением

> HEAP_CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block(#152) at 0x00ED7A48 
>   CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer;

при попытке удалить второй объект?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Почему вызывается конструктор A()

Потому что вы создаете обьект этого типа, чтобы добавить в конец вектора.

> почему программа падает с сообщением

При вызове  `std::vector::push_back` вектор просит своему распределителью выделять память для одного элемента(на самом деле резервируется память с запасом_ буфер элементов, чтобы каждый раз не выполнить выделение). Для этого вызывается `Allocator::allocate` с аргументом `1(один элемент)`. У вас же эта функция выделит память на `один байт`, поскольку вы вызываете `malloc(1)`, а нужно как минимум sizeof(T) байт.

И технически ваш распределитель пока еще не подходит для использования в векторе, поскольку отсутствуют много необходимых определений (в частности `Allocator::rebind`,  `Allocator::reallocate`,  псевдонимы всех нужных типов и т.д.) , плюс, если `malloc` не найдет достаточной памяти, то никогда не будет генерироваться исключение, поскольку  `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / sizeof(T)` вполне может быть, например, восемьнадцизначным число (сами посчитайте сколько гиг). Так что эту ошибку тоже нужно исправлять.

А вообше я бы использовал `new` и `delete` потому что разница времени выполнения неощутимая, и `new` вызывает `new_hendler`, когда не может найти память, и теперь функция `new_hendler` пытается найти память используя другую стратегию. А malloc этого не делает...